# Upgrade option grayed out in intaller

Tags: upgrade

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 on a Gigabyte GA-81915G-MF motherboard with a Pentium 4 2.6Gb CPU, 1GB RAM and 160GB HD. I'm quite happy with this and prefer it over my Microsoft computer which I only use for the odd program not available in a Linux version.

I decided to upgrade to 11.10 since I've gotten to like Unity which I use on my eeePC with 10.04. I purchased the latest issue of Ubuntu User with 11.10 on the DVD (to save on download allowance), checked the integrity of the disc and proceeded to install.

All seemed to go fine until I went to choose the UPGRADE option on the menu, and the menu would not allow me to choose it. For some weird reason it would skip over it to the next option. I'd never come across this before, and there was no explanation.

I tried several times and even approached it from the Live Version as well as the boot option. But no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can directly upgrade from 10.04 to 11.10, you would need to upgrade to 10.10 first, then 11.04.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes

Honestly with all the changes and potential problems / hassles of upgrading, not to mention bandwidth, I would back up my data and do a fresh install.

If you do not already have one, making a separate /home partition can be helpful as well.